# Knowing web sql database is already created or not

Tags: sqlite, cordova

Is there any way to know wheather new database is created or connected to existing one, when calling window.openDatabase() ? I think i have to create tables only when newly created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about the openDatabase() command. Instead modify your SQL so it only creates the tables if they don't exist like so:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)
```